# First two terms of $\sin(\sin(2x))$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I'm asked to find first two terms of the series $\sin(\sin(2x))$.

$$\sin(t) = t-\frac{t^3}{3!}+\frac{t^5}{5!}-\cdots$$

$$\sin(2x) = 2x-\frac{2^3x^3}{3!}+\frac{2^5x^5}{5!}-\cdots$$

$$\displaystyle \sin(\sin(2x)) = (2x-\frac{2^3x^3}{3!}+\frac{2^5x^5}{5!}-\cdots)-\frac{(2x-\frac{2^3x^3}{3!}+\frac{2^5x^5}{5!}-\cdots)^3
}{3!}+\cdots$$

The cubed term and those beyond don't contribute anything to the first two terms, so

$$\sin(\sin(2x)) = 2x-\frac{2^3x^3}{3!}+\cdots$$

However, this is wrong. What have I missed?

Comment: Expanding the numerator of the second term gives $8x^3 + O(x^5)$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you! xD

Answer (score 2):

All of your derivations using the taylor series are correct.

However, when you use the taylor series of $\sin(\sin(2x))$, you didn't note the following terms that contributes to the $x^3$ term:

$$\displaystyle \sin(\sin(2x)) = (2x-\frac{2^3x^3}{3!}+\frac{2^5x^5}{5!}-\cdots)-\frac{(2x-\frac{2^3x^3}{3!}+\frac{2^5x^5}{5!}-\cdots)^3
}{3!}+\cdots$$

In your second term, you have the term $2x$ part of an cubed polynomial. This indicates that one of the terms, when expanded, is $(2x)^3 = 8x^3$.

Therefore, when simplifying, we add this term to get:

$$\displaystyle \sin(\sin(2x)) = 2x - \frac{8x^3}{6} - \frac{8x^3}{6} + \cdots$$

$$\displaystyle \sin(\sin(2x)) = 2x - \frac{8x^3}{3} + \cdots$$